# How to save view controls as snapshat and re-use many times in same android Acticity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am building a vocabulary building app. It involves displaying words, its meaning,usage etc using several textviews in an Activity layout. The user can navigate to next word by single tap, previous word on double tap. I don't want to populate the TextViews each time when the user goes back to a previous word. Is it possible to save the whole screen controls as a dataset and re use it?

[Sample layout image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9zOc.png)

Comment: Several TextViews? Can you provide the screen diagram or sample UI for example?

Comment: I see hardly around 5 textviews here. Creating the snapshot and storing would be higher Overhead when compared to reloading them again. Just for confirmation, are you fetching the data from the server or Local DB?

Comment: local DB. The new layout will not have a search box. Say ten words will be loaded from the Db. The user should be able to navigate forward or backward at any point of time.

Comment: OK, first things first, your requirements are misleading. Second thing, you dont need snapshot for 100 words also. Third thing use RecyclerView if you have list of words instead of using Several TextViews. Last but main thing. provide more details of your requirement as with current requirement I dont see any use of SnapShots.

Comment: @RamKumar, Hi Ram, your question is bit ambiguous :) As per my I understanding of your requirement and UI design, you don't need to cache UI controls rather then you need to update your UI for loading previous and next word from local db. This will work even if you will use search on your current screen. Thanks